# Broken Linux kernel, can't reinstall it

Tags: linux, boot, grub, arch-linux, kernel

I got `/boot/vmlinuz-linux not found` while booting my Arch Linux. I know the kernel is damaged and I have to reinstall the kernel. But the problem is: I don't have ANY bootable devices, and also, I haven't installed ANY other OS in my PC. This is also my only 1 PC. The only thing I can access in my PC is GRUB command-line or GRUB rescue. Now what can I do? Can I use this GRUB rescue to boot an ISO file? Or can I make a bootable USB? Or can I chroot to the installation to reinstall the kernel?

I only have one mobile phone now, which I am using to post this... and it is not rooted.

**EDIT:** And also this phone does NOT support OTG.

What can I do other than going to the shop to repair the PC?

Comment: There are some Android apps that claim to be able to write iso images to USB and don't require root on your phone. Might be able to download an Arch iso to a USB stick that way? https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=eu.depau.etchdroid

Comment: @Mokubai - Thanks for your reply, but sadly OTG does not work in my phone.

Comment: The kernel is damaged: what kind of damage? Does your phone work as Mass Storage Device when connected to the PC with USB?

Comment: @golimar How do I check?

Comment: back when your PC worked, when you connected it to the PC did it show exactly like a USB drive, with a drive letter, etc?

Comment: As I mentioned, I had Arch Linux, so probably it doesn't have drive letter system. All files are inside the root (/) folder in Linux. And by the way, it shows like a normal mobile device, with my device model name.